# Definition of a solution of a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In one of the books, I found that, the definition stated as 'solution of the differential equation is

Given an open interval $I$ that consists to, a solution of the initial value problem 
$$
               X' = f(X,t)       ~~\text{   with  }~~  X(t_o) = X_o   \tag{1.1}
$$
['$t$' is the independent variable]

on $I$ is a differentiable function $x(t)$ defined on $I$, with $x(t_o) = x_o$  and $x'(t) = f(x,t)$ for all $t ϵ I$.'

My questions are,

1. What does open interval mean in this contest?
2. Why it can't be a closed interval?

Thanks in advance,
Ram.

Comment: Just in general, non-open sets don't play nice with derivatives, since you wind up having to take them from just one side (or, in higher dimensions, from a restricted subset of all possible directions). In any case, a solution to an initial value problem can always have its domain extended to some maximal open interval where it will be a solution.

Comment: sorry for the late response. What 'does open interval' means in this contest? I am not a mathematician. So, sorry if you find my doubt very silly or naive.

Comment: An open interval $(a,b)$ consists of real numbers strictly between $a$ and $b$, not included. This means that for any number $x$ in $(a,b)$, there is some open interval containing $x$ which is entirely contained in $(a,b)$. This in turn means that you can take derivatives from any side. By contrast, on a closed interval, you can only take derivatives at the endpoints from one side.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have one more doubt and please help me with that. You mentioned 'on a closed interval, you can only take derivatives at the endpoints from one side' - why is that? why can we take derivatives from any side if its an open interval? and why we can take derivatives at the endpoints from one side if its a closed interval?

Comment: If I have a function defined on a closed interval and I want to differentiate it at the right endpoint, I can't perturb my input out to the right, because the function isn't even defined there. So the only thing I can do is take a left-sided derivative, which tends to lead to some technical mathematical issues. An open interval doesn't have this problem, because as I said, for any $x$ in $(a,b)$ there is an open interval containing $x$ which is entirely contained in $(c,d)$, so I can move from $x$ in either direction (at least a small amount).

Comment: thanks for answering my questions. Its clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Since there doesn't seem to be any further discussion, I'm copying my comment above into an answer:

Just in general, non-open sets don't play nice with derivatives, since you wind up having to take them from just one side (or, in higher dimensions, from a restricted subset of all possible directions). In any case, a solution to an initial value problem can always have its domain extended to some maximal open interval where it will be a solution.